# Controller return image for use in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to convert an existing WinForms application to a MVC Web Application.

I am attempting to display an image from a controller.

At the moment I get a System.Drawing.Image back from a function and I am trying to work out how to supply this to the View.

This is my controller:

```
public System.Drawing.Image getStudentImage(string PersonID)
{
        System.Drawing.Image studentImage = ClientFunctions.GetStudentImage(GlobalVariables.networkstuff, GlobalVariables.testAuth, PersonID);
        return studentImage;
}
```

And then, in my View I would like to display this image...

Hopefully, like this:

```
<img id="@pupil.PupilInfo.PersonID" src="~/TakeRegister/getStudentImage/@pupil.PupilInfo.PersonID" alt="" />
```

When I run the code I get broken images in the browser and when I look at the "src" of the image it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:19340/TakeRegister/getStudentImage/3058
```

I get the feeling I am doing more than 1 thing wrong here... (?)

Can anyone give me any pointers please?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1vvAdl7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to render System.Drawing.Image in ASP.NET MVC 3 View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546865/best-way-to-render-system-drawing-image-in-asp-net-mvc-3-view)

Comment: @AntP thanks! - works perfectly... i was obviously phrasing my question incorrectly in google as i didn't find that :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `return File()` in your action.

```
public ActionResult Image(int PersonID)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image image = ClientFunctions.GetStudentImage(GlobalVariables.networkstuff, GlobalVariables.testAuth, PersonID);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
            }
        }
```