# c# MVC display image from viewmodel in a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass an image stored in a viewmodel from my controller to my razor view. The two [barcode] images (`System.Drawing.Image`) are defined as below:

```
ShippingSummaryViewModel shippingSummaryVm = ShippingSummaryViewModel.ToShippingSummaryFromOrder(orders);
shippingSummaryVm.CustIdBarcode = CreateBarcode(shippingSummaryVm.customer_code);
shippingSummaryVm.SalesOrderBarcode = CreateBarcode(shippingSummaryVm.order_id);
```

in my view, I would like to be able to use an `<img>` tag to reference these images but I am not sure what to put for the source as setting the src equal to `@Model.CustIdBarcode` does not work due to getting a 404 resource not found error. All help is appreciated

Edit: In my razor view, I am using `<img src="@Model.SalesOrderBarcode"/>` and `<img src="@Model.CustIdBarcode" />` to try and display the images. These fields in my viewmodel look like:

```
public Image SalesOrderBarcode { get; set; }
public Image CustIdBarcode { get; set; }
```

and the errors I get when rendering the page are:

```
GET http://localhost:63957/Orders/System.Drawing.Bitmap 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML images are generally linked to another request on the server, so passing the `System.Drawing.Image` is not the best way to do this. Modern browsers can have inline images (base64 encoded), but the best bet is to create a different action on the controller that you can link to:

```
public class MyController {
  public ActionResult GetCustIdBarCode(Guid code) {
    var img = CreateBarcode(code);

    // I'm not sure if the using here will work or not. It might work
    // to just remove the using block if you have issues.
    using (var strm = new MemoryStream()) {
      img.Save(strm, "image/png");
      return File(strm, "image/png");
    }
  }

  public ActionResult GetSalesBarcode(Guid salesId) {
    // Similar to above method
  }
}
```

And then in your view, you'd have something like:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetCustIdBarCode", new { code = customer_code })" />
```

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546957/179311

Answer (score 1):

In your View try like this

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: I don't have a path to my image as I don't want to store it anywhere (it will have a very short lifespan). My viewmodel directly contains the image I'd like to render

Comment: So that you can return image to base64 in action result

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
<img src="@Url.ImagePath(Model.CustIdBarcode)" />
```